# Can we lower a planet temperature by radiating electromagnetic waves?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation, planets

If cold cannot be achieved without producing heat somewhere else, I was wondering could said heat be sent to outer space using a microwave ray or any other electromagnetic radiation, and thus lowering a planet's temperature?

Note: I am not concerned with engineering questions nor how insignificant such a temp change would be. I just want to know if known laws of physics allow cooling using a focused energy beam as heat removal.

Comment: When I think about that I imagine big airconditioners cooling the atmosphere. The bottle with the compressed hot gass that must be heated inside that device to produce colder atmosphere should be put in the center of a parabolic mirror which will emit produced paralel red light rays towards the sky... In reality very difficult...

Comment: Yeah, big air conditioner, exactly. Could generated heat be disposed of without a material medium (gas), using radiations instead? I like the parabolic mirror idea, as it can be used to focus infrared radiation. If one use the hot exhaust of an air conditioner to warm some catalyst, can the radiation be sent in space? I don't see why not (as long as atmosphere is transparent to that wavelength though)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question, so do clarify if this isn't what you meant.

Of course! All objects radiate energy, including planets like the Earth. It's the reason we're alive today! If all the energy radiated by the sun was absorbed by the Earth without it radiating most of this out into space (as it does), we'd all be charred very quickly ;) The Earth is constantly radiating energy out into space at a rate proportional to the fourth power of its temperature. For more information, read up on the [Stefan-Boltzmann Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).

Comment: As you suspected, this has nothing to do with my question. I am rather interested in artificially accelerating a planet heat dissipation so as to cool it down.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a ray of heat. To generate a ray of energy will just create more heat. What we can do in principle is increase the planetary heat emission by reducing athmospheric greenhouse gas concentrations, produce less heat, increase reflectivity by painting our roofs white or even make them reflective etc.

Comment: Geothermal energy can be used to vaporize water, run turbines, make electricity and use it to generate microwaves that can be sent to a satellite. So this energy conversion is possible. Why a gradient between ground temp and, say, some cooler cave water could not transformed into disposable energy? I never talked about a ray of heat, although your roofs would reflect rays of heat (infrared, if only).